# Testing a component with Jest Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, tdd

I have this component in my codebase,

```
    <template>
    <v-dialog v-model="modalVisible" content-class="muc-modal" max-width="350" persistent>
        <v-card>
            <component :is="component"/>
        </v-card>

    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { namespace } from "vuex-class";

const Modal = namespace("Modals");

@Component
export default class AppModal extends Vue {

    public component: any = null;

    @Modal.State
    public modalVisible!: boolean;
    @Modal.State
    public modalComponent!: string;
    @Modal.State
    public modalComponentPath!: string|null;


    get injectedComponent() {
        return this.modalComponent;
    }

    @Modal.Mutation
    public hideModal!: () => void

    @Watch('injectedComponent')
    onModalComponent(componentName: string) {
        if(!componentName) return;
        this.component = Vue.component(componentName, () => import(`./${this.modalComponentPath}`));
    }


}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

.muc-modal {
    width:350px;
    max-width:90%;
}

</style>
```

It is modal component that takes another component, this is run via mutation on the modal store,

```
 import { VuexModule, Module, Mutation, Action } from "vuex-module-decorators";

@Module({ namespaced: true })
export default class Modals extends VuexModule {

    //#region "State"
    public modalVisible: boolean = false;
    public modalComponent: string|null = null;
    public modalComponentPath: string|null = null;
    //#endregion "State"

    //#region "Mutations"
    @Mutation
    public showModal(modalComponent:string, modalComponentPath: string|null = null) {
        this.modalVisible = true;
        this.modalComponent = modalComponent
        this.modalComponentPath = modalComponentPath ? modalComponentPath : modalComponent
    }

    @Mutation
    public hideModal() {
        this.modalVisible = false;
        this.modalComponent = null;
        this.modalComponentPath = null;
    }
    //#endregion "Mutations"

    //#region "Getters"
    get getVisibility(): boolean {
        return this.modalVisible
    }
    //#endregion "Getters"

    //#region "Actions"
    //#endregion "Actions"


}
```

I am wanting to write some tests that a) test the modal display correctly when `showModal()` mutation is run, b) that it gets hidden correctly when `hideModal()` mutation is run.

This is my current test file,

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Modals from '@/store/modal';
import AppModal from '@/components/AppModal.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(Vuex);

describe('AppModal.vue', () => {

    let store: any = null;
    //let mutations = modals.mutations

    beforeEach(() => {

        store = new Vuex.Store({
            modules: {
                "modals" : Modals
            }
        })
    
    });

    it('shows modal when modalVisible is set to true', () => {
        console.log(store);
        const wrapper =  shallowMount(AppModal, {store, localVue});
        // const modal = wrapper.find('.muc-modal')
        // console.log(modal);

    })

});
```

running this test I get the following response,

> console.error node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:916
> [vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): Modals/
>
> console.error node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:916
> [vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): Modals/
>
> console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of null"
>
> ```
> found in
>
> ---> <AppModal>
> ```

and i have no clue why, can anyone help shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1):

This error -

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of null

Is a direct result of this coding error -

```
<component :is="null" />
```

**Why?**

The component tag should never have a null value for the `is` attribute, even if it's momentary. `null` isn't a valid component, and Jest correctly finds this error even when you don't see it in the browser.

In your above code, the initial value for the property `component` (which is probably a bad variable name) is `null`, so that's where this is coming from. A simple fix would be to set a valid component as an initial value so that it is never null.